# Read excel file (.xlsx or .xls) with displayed formatting (indentation)?

Tags: c#, excel

I want read all data from file with the same formatting as showing when I open excel file. I mean the same indent, which is set in "Format cell". All methods I tried works fine but remove indentation (formatting).

Checked already ExcelDataReader, Oledb, Interop.

Comment: Use Excel interop. Access formatting through the Excel API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EasyXLS Excel Reader](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-reader). You can read both xls or xlsx files.

This code sample reads the value and the indent from A1 cell:

```
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();

// Read XLSX file
workbook.easy_LoadXLSXFile("file.xlsx");

// Get the table of the first worksheet
ExcelTable table = ((ExcelWorksheet)workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0)).easy_getExcelTable();

//Get the value from A1 cell
String value = table.easy_getCell(0, 0).getValue();

//Get the indent from A1 cell
int indent = table .easy_getCell(0, 0).getStyle().getIndent();
```

You can also read other formatting settings. In a similar way you can read xls files also.